# Is there any page load data generated in GA for a page that times out and shows a blank?

Tags: google-analytics, timeout, sitespeed

I am managing a website where a dynamic landing page, due to a badly written/optimized code, often **times out after a few seconds and shows a blank**. After refreshing, the page loads but it usually takes long time.

To assess the issue, I am looking at the avg. page load time in GA at *Behaviour/Site Speed/Page Timings* and I can see a value of **11.62 sec**.

Does this value contain any data about page loads that timed out before they could finish loading?

In case not, is there a way I can see any data about the page's time outs (for example how many user sessions were affected by it)?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If a page load is timing out (say a 500 error) then there would be not GA event firing. If the page is loading but then the data is loading dynamically and timing out, then you would want to use a custom event to learn when it's loaded or perhaps a gtm timer trigger to see if at x seconds the data has loaded or not.

The GA feature you are most closely describing is known as [User Timings](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-timings), but there is no default feature for a timeout of a dynamic element, you'd need to create the measurement event (aka the timing hit).